# Difference Between "Number of Sessions" and "App Launches" in FB Analytics

Tags: facebook, analytics, facebook-analytics

What is the difference between "Number of Sessions" (under the active users tab -> Completed sessions chart -> Metric -> Number of sessions) and "App Launches" (standard event) in FB Analytics? I understood them to be the same- but my weekly data is showing app launches as dramatically higher than number of sessions.

FB analytics help center defines "App Launches" as "The number of times a user opened your app after having not used it within the last minute. Multiple opens from the same user within one minute register as a single app launch. App launches are based on the app activation event."

I have no been able to find a definition of "number of sessions" on the fb analytics help center or on google. But, FB does say "Depending on the channel, Facebook Analytics uses one or both of the following events to log session data: app activation and deactivation. Learn about logging iOS and Android app activation events. If a session is interrupted for less than 60 seconds, we'll ignore the interruption and combine session times."

Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not an actual programming question.

Answer (score 0):

As facebook analytics help states:

> Once 30 minutes of inactivity have passed with no additional actions
> taken, the current session ends and we'll log subsequent actions as a
> new session.

Example also included in the refrence:
https://www.facebook.com/help/analytics/1998967943655628